# Simplicial Complexes - the Closure of the Star is a Cone on the Link (proof?)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff

I'm trying to prove that $\overline{st_K(x)}$ is a cone on $lk_K(x)$, but can't seem to get anywhere!

I know how to construct a topological cone given a space $X$. However I don't know any way to test whether a space **is** a cone on another space. Could someone give me a hint for this, and possibly outline some methods I might employ in the future for similar problems?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a picture. Alternately, refer to the picture at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_complex#Closure.2C_star.2C_and_link). The easiest way to prove something is a cone based on some space is to figure out exactly what cone it is (in this case, the cone on $lk_K(x)$ from $x$ itself). In order to prove this you'll need to go to the definitions of the objects involved.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I definitely see why it's intuitively true, but I've written down the definition and I can't see how to come up with a conclusive proof. I guess my question really is - if $X=lk(x)$ then find an explicit homeomorphism $CX \rightarrow \overline{st(x)}$. Any ideas what my homeomorphism should be for a general simplicial complex of dimension $n$? Thanks!

Comment: @hgbreton It mostly depends on how you defined simplices, but there should be a way to construct a natural isomorphism between any n-simplex and the cone from one of its (n-1)-faces to the vertex not included in that face.